# S parameter model of the capacitor

Tags: capacitor, simulation, decoupling-capacitor, s-parameters, power-integrity

For same capacitor, there is no s-parameter model, so can we use the model from other manufacturer of the same spec.

Eg:
Caps with model - C0603C104K5RACTU - KEMET - Cap, Cer-X7R, 0.1uF, 50V, 10%, 0603
without model   - 0603B104K500CT - Walsin - Cap, Cer-X7R, 0.1uF, 50V, 10%, 0603

Both have same spec, but for walsin component there is no data of ESR and SRF, so whether we can you model of KEMET for walsin cap. Because while we do decoupling simulation for caps, it is hard to import data for the caps that dont have models or RLC values.

Comment: Just use the cap from KEMET.

Comment: But the cost,  walsin components are low in cost.

Comment: You pay extra for better documentation.